# Clearing the Dhcp and dns cache of android

Tags: android, dns, ip

Is there way to clear the dns cache of android device pogrammatically??.I search lot on google but didnt find anything regarding this.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2101762/android-flush-dns

Comment: sorry my bad I  forgot to add word programmatically in my question

Answer (score 1):

As root, do in a shell:

> ndc resolver flushdefaultif

And if you want to do it programatically, try this piece of code:

```
    public boolean reboot() {
    Process proc = null;
    try {
        proc = Runtime.getRuntime().exec("su");
        proc.getOutputStream().write(("ndc resolver flushdefaultif").getBytes());
        return proc.waitFor() == 0;
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    catch (InterruptedException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    return false;
}
```

Comment: On Android 4.3, at least, you can open an `adb shell` console, and give the command `ndc resolver flushdefaultif` which will be  shown  as "command succeeded" (while `ndc resolver flushdefault` is "500 0 Resolver unknown command") ... and when you ping your dynamic server from an `adb shell` again, it will still fail.